# Do I need to do anything special to use NPTL (as opposed to pthreads)?

Tags: linux, pthreads, nptl

Do I need to do anything special to use NPTL instead of pthreads? I am on kernel 2.3.23...

I am asking because I am looking at some code which is presumably working with NPTL but I can see that it still includes pthreads, which AFAIK has problems like signal handling at thread level, spurious wake-ups, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No.

NPTL is a newer *implementation* of POSIX threads, which is used on any reasonably modern Linux distribution.

The older implementation -- LinuxThreads -- was boken in many ways, and you are unlikely to ever encounter it.

Both implementations *are* pthreads.

Answer (score 0):

The threading implementation is chosen at configure time of the c runtime library, typically [glibc (see the example for `--enable-add-ons`)](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html).